# What doesn't VirtualBox allow promiscous mode on NAT-based network?

Tags: virtualbox

When I switch network mode to `NAT` mode, there's no options regarding `Promiscous Mode` anymore.

So VirtualBox explicitly doesn't allow it. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Promiscuous mode" means the VM is allowed to receive Ethernet packets sent to different MAC addresses than its own.

In "NAT" mode, each VM is behind a virtual router that performs IP address translation in pretty much the same way home routers/gateways with NAT do – as a side effect it rejects any incoming packets unless they belong to a connection already established by the VM.

This means that the VM will never receive packets sent to other Ethernet addresses because 100% of them would be discarded by the NAT, so the `promisc` option would be ineffective anyway.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, in NAT mode each VM is separated, althrough it has IP address in the same sub network, right?

Comment: @warl0ck: Yes. Each VM is behind its own NAT gateway, and even though all of them use the same IP address range, they still cannot see each other because of two NATs between every VM. It is similar to several customers of the same ISP, each behind their own NAT gateway, each using `192.168.1.0/24`, but none of them seeing each other directly.